# Jquery append MVC PartialView with scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have javascript function which appends `PartialView` into div. Everything works fine, except that PartialView contains some `<script></script>` scripts. And those dynamically appended functions are not found by jQuery - `Uncaught ReferenceError: getIDc4 is not defined`.

My JS function

```
var url = '@UrlHelper.GetFullUrl("Inventories/GetFilterRow")'; //this returns partial view
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { aRef: aRef },
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                $('.filter').append($(data)[0]);
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.type = 'text/javascript';
                script.src = url;
            }
        });
```

and partial view

```
...
@{
    int id = Model != null ? Model.Id : 1;
}

<div id="@Html.Raw("FilterCondition" + id)">
...
...
...

    @{
        string getIdcFunction = string.Format("getIDc{0}", id);
    }
    <script>
        @{
            @:function  
                @getIdcFunction<text>() {
            var grid = $("@Html.Raw("#field"+id)").data("kendoDropDownList");
            var item = grid.value();
            return { IDc: item };
        }
            </text>
        }
    </script>

</div>
```

How can I get those dynamically appended functions get working?

When I generate the partial view by using on page loading with

```
@Html.Partial("GetFilterRow", new {Id = 1})
```

everything works fine. The only problem is when this view is appendend via jquery and ajax. Then those functions are not found.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Never put scripts in partials. Put them in the main view or layout

Comment: yes, but I need it in this case... Is there any workaround to get this working?

Comment: Why do you think you need it? What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: well I need to generate the function with names like name1, name2, name3 ... the reason is that, the external component, which I use, doesn't support function parameters for callback, so I can't just call name(id), I can only specify the name of the function, so thus for every component I create a new function.... it is ugly but I don't see other workaround

Comment: Does the external component contain a reference back to the original element?  Perhaps you could use jQuery $.data() to set custom data on each element and then retrieve it in your callback?

Edit: you could also try moving the script outside of the <div> tag and give it type="text/javascript".  jQuery should automatically parse script tags.  Take a look at Microsoft's jQuery.unobtrusive-ajax.js for an example of how they handle Ajax.ActionLink.  Scripts in Partial Views using this method are parsed and executed just fine.

Comment: looks like the JS you wrote using razor is wrong. can you show the rendered JS ?

Comment: @JSantosh , JS should be fine, when I render it using PartialView it works. Only problem is when I append it using ajax and jQuery, then the functions are not found...

Comment: @MichaelGagne could you please provide me a link to that examples? thanks

Comment: Finally I found other workaround how to deal with those components without need to generate new functions in PartialView... anyway I still wonder if this is possible somehow

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options that I am aware of.  Option one is to include your script in the main view and set the `onclick` or whichever event you're trying to call to call that function.

For example, in your main view have:

```
function floorSelect(clickedFloor) {
         doStuff;
         }
```

And in your partial view have:

```
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labeledby="dropDownSelectFloor">
                @For i As Integer = 0 To Model.ListOfFloors.Count - 1
                    @<li role="presentation"><a id="ddListSelectFloor" class="ddListSelectFloor" 
                     onclick="floorSelect(this)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                     @Model.ListOfFloors(i)</a>
                        </li>
                    Next
                </ul>
```

Notice the `onClick` which calls the script from the main view.

Option number 2 is to attach the script via `id`(you can probably do this to the `class` as well)

Like this:

```
@For i As Integer = 0 To Model.ListOfDisplayTypes.Count - 1
                If Model.ListOfDisplayTypes(i).Equals("DatePicker") Then
                @<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <b>@Model.ListOfFields(i): </b>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input class="search" id="@Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)" type="text" placeholder="@Model.ListOfFields(i)">
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        jQuery("input[id='@Model.ListOfCategoryAttributeIDs(i)']").datepicker();
                    </script>
                </div>
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Put the scripts in the partial view into scripts.js file.
2.After you append the partial view into the div use `$.getscripts('path of scripts.js')`.

Comment: good idea . but this will not work because OP is writing JS in razor . check the OP once , you can see text tags. so it is not just JS, it is something like  dynamic JS code